# How to get sublime to auto suggest import statements for java

Tags: sublimetext2

I am using sublime text 2 and I was wondering if just like netbeans sublime would suggest class files import. Like when I use say a jLabel it should offer to add the statement,

```
import javax.swing.jLabel;
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a Sublime text snippet that allows you to automatically add imports by just referencing the package you want in `uppercase` and pressing `TAB key`. See [JavaIME](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JavaIME)